# how to handle different datepickers options differently on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am having 2 datepickers on the same page.  One is name datePicker1 and the other datePicker2.  I am actually having the code

```
$(".ui-state-active").parents('tr').css("border", "1px solid Green");
        $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr").live('click', function(){
           $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").css("border", "1px solid Green");
        });
```

I want to have the above code to work only for datePicker1 and not 2.  Actually, the problem is that the code is working on both datepickers.  How can I make it work for only datePicker1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly sure where your name is specified but if you got a name attribute on the .ui-datepicker-calendar element try it with this:

```
$(".ui-state-active").parents('tr').css("border", "1px solid Green");
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar[name=datePicker1] tbody tr").live('click', function(){
       $(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:nth-child(" + ($(this).index() + 1) + ")").css("border", "1px solid Green");
    });
```

Otherwise it would be great if you could provide a jsfiddle with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Give the datepicker object an ID or better yet give its parent an id and select that specific item instead of a generic class.

Comment: I have the datepicker id as  $("#datePicker1").datepicker({...}) and $("#datePicker2").datepicker({...}), how to do it? I have tried $("datePicker1.ui-state-active").parents('tr').css("border", "1px solid Green"); 
but it`s not working

Comment: I'm not sure what your HTML looks like. For starters you're missing a # in the selector. At this point I'm not sure what .ui-state-active is. is the `tr` a parent of #datePicker1 or the other way around?

Could we see the page or the markup for the datepicker please?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, you shouldn't use `.live()`. It hogs resources and is actually deprecated.

Here's a good way of doing it with a delegate:

```
$("body").on('click', '.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr', function(){
       $(this).next().css("border", "1px solid Green");
 });
```

The bad thing here is that despite this, there's no easy way to differentiate which input field started the datepicker.

What i would do is hook up a `.focus()` event to the datepicker fields, and add a class if it's the field you want the effect on, otherwise remove it.

Like so:

```
$(".datepicker").focus(function() { 
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "datePicker1") {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").addClass("greenBorders");
    } 
    else {
        $("#ui-datepicker-div").removeClass("greenBorders");
    }
});
```

And then update the above code like so:

```
$("body").on('click', '.greenBorders ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr', function(){
       $(this).next().css("border", "1px solid Green");
 });
```

Comment: I am not using anything like focus

Comment: Then you're pretty boned - the datepicker div isn't created until focus is put on the input element, and goes away with the focus, so I can think of no other way to "bind" it to a particular field.